# MVC areas for sites with different content

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

We have 3 CMS sites that differ from each other only by some content. e.g. 1st one is used to fill the content for a person, that has Name and Surname, the 2nd one fills the same person's content, but the person has also Age, the 3rd one is filled in the same manner.
The question is, would it be a good approach to use 3 areas for these 3 CMS sites and toggle between them from the main menu for instance?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is overkill. Areas usually are used for separating different parts of web application(Like administrative and client parts).
Yours basically is a person editor with 3 different roles of users. It is possible to create a single controller with Edit action and depending on user role show corresponding layout.

Comment: the sample with Person was just an example, in theory there can be also different logic for each controller. If we use one controller for all sites, there will be lots of if's and switches then in code.